# How to validate CDATA section for an XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I create an XML based on user input. One of the xml nodes has a CDATA section. If one of the characters inserted in the CDATA section is 'special' (a control character I think) then the entire xml becomes invalid.

Example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('root'))
    ->appendChild($dom->createCDATASection(
        "This is some text with a SOH char \x01."
    ));

$test = new DOMDocument;
$test->loadXml($dom->saveXML());
echo $test->saveXml();
```

will give

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): CData section not finished
This is some text with a SOH cha in Entity, line: 2 in /newfile.php on line 17

Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): PCDATA invalid Char value 1 in Entity, line: 2 in /newfile.php on line 17

Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Sequence ']]>' not allowed in content in Entity, line: 2 in /newfile.php on line 17

Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Sequence ']]>' not allowed in content in Entity, line: 2 in /newfile.php on line 17

Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): internal errorExtra content at the end of the document in Entity, line: 2 in /newfile.php on line 17
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

Is there a good way in php do make sure the CDATA section is valid ?

Comment: Somehow the users copy/paste the SOH control character

Comment: Well, you can simply sanitize the input by either using whitelist or blacklist character map. I would start from `filter_var([], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)`.

Comment: It is a humongous bummer that `DOMDocument` does not take steps to guarantee XML output. CDATA containing `]]>` or control characters is not checked, and comment nodes containing `--` is not checked either. Both are easy ways to create invalid XML even using `DOMDocument`.

Comment: @FrancisAvila DOM does have some checks to prevent invalid XML though. I was actually suprised that it wouldnt prevent control chars in CDATA sections.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The allowed [range of characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Char) for [CDATA section](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-cdsection) is

```
#x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]
```

So you have to sanitize your string to include only those characters.

Comment: It's there any build in function for this ?

Comment: @danip not that I know of. try `preg_match`.

Answer (score 2):

Because the "\x01" is not a printable character . So cause the Warning .You can solution this problem like this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('root'))
->appendChild($dom->createCDATASection(
    urlencode("This is some text with a SOH char \x01.")
));

$test = new DOMDocument;
$test->loadXml($dom->saveXML());
echo urldecode($test->saveXml());
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Gordon's answer, I made:

```
 /**
 * Removes invalid characters from an HTML string
 *
 * @param string $content
 *
 * @return string
 */
function sanitize_html($content) {
  if (!$content) return '';
  $invalid_characters = '/[^\x9\xa\x20-\xD7FF\xE000-\xFFFD]/';
  return preg_replace($invalid_characters, '', $content);
}
```

Use like:

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at `simplexml_load_file` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) `LIBXML_NOCDATA` option (http://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php). This will most likely answer your question.

Comment: I understood the OP is asking about the generation of the XML not about the reading of it.

Comment: you might want to update your question with your comment about filter_var although filter_var might not work when the OP needs arbitrary unicode.